# Rbind the files with filenames/patterns included in a column of a source file using R

Tags: r, loops, csv, rbind

I am trying to rbind thousands of files which are found in a column of a source file. The filenames of the files that I need to rbind are as follows:
_1.csv, __1.csv,___1.csv, _2.csv., 3.csv, _3.csv etc.

The source file is this:

[image]

Since the filename contains "1", the city where those csv files belong is at City A.

Thus, my desired output is to make a new file named A.csv
with rbind contents of _1.csv, __1.csv, ___1.csv, and _2.csv.  Another  is to make a new B.csv file which contains the rbind contents of all the filenames with "3" in it (3.csv and _3.csv).

I am dealing with a big data thus thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

This has been not tested, but might help

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "_.*csv")

write_to_csv <- function(x, y){
  if(file.exists(y)){
    write.csv(x, file=y, append = T, col.names = F, row.names = F)
  } else
    write.csv(x, file=y, row.names = F)
}


for(f in files){
  x <- read.csv(f)

  if(grepl("1|2", f)){
    write_to_csv(x, "A.csv")

  } else if(grepl("3", f)){
    write_to_csv(x, "B.csv")
  }
}
```

Comment: hi sir, i am actually dealing with thousands of files so i am avoiding the method you have posted above -.- do you happen to know other functions in rstudio that could help me avoid the code you posted above?

Comment: Why are you avoiding the approach above? Is it crashing?

Comment: @karate if you work in linux/mac OS, I suggest to use  `cat` command in the terminal, like: `cat *1.csv > A.csv`